# Is this Python code equivalent of Java code?

Tags: java, python

I'm fairly new to Python so please bear with me.

This is the Java code:

```
public static int countDeafRats(final String town) {
    String t = town.replaceAll(" ","");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < t.length() ; i+=2) 
        if (t.charAt(i) == 'O') count++;
    return count;
}
```

This is my attempt to translate it to Python:

```
def count_deaf_rats(town):
    count = 0
    increment = 0
    newTown = town.replace(" ", "")
    while increment <= len(newTown):
        if newTown[increment]=='O':
            count +=1
            increment +=2
    return count
```

I didn't use for loop in Python since I don't how to increment by 2, so as the title says, would this be an acceptable translation?

Edit, sample input: `~O~O~O~OP~O~OO~`

Comment: Indenting is wrong. Everything below `def` should be indented to the right

Comment: Can you show an example input and your expected output? Rather than a straight translation, there's probably a pythonic way to do this naturally.

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range for increment by 2... `for i in range(0, newTown, 2):`

Comment: You would never use a `while` loop here in Python, but by glancing at it, it looks equivalent.

Comment: The `increment += 2` should not be inside the if-block

Comment: @rollback ah, good catch. A great example of why one should just use a `for` loop, and not worry about silly iteration logic errors like this.

Comment: If you have the increment in the if block you may end up with a while true if your string isn't particularly formatted as expected.

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: @Mandy8055 number of "rats" that are not facing the 'P'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to find the number of zeroes in the string that occur at indices incremented by 2. You can use regex and list comprehensions in Python:

```
import re

new_town = re.sub("\s+", '', town)

count = sum(i == "0" for i in new_town[::2])
```

Comment: Or just `sum(c == "0" for c in new_town[::2])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your suggestion. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much Java, but I believe this is a more direct translation of your code into python:

```
def countDeafRats(town):
    count = 0
    new_town = town.replace(' ','')
#format for range: start, end (exclusive), increment
    for i in range(0, len(new_town), 2):
        if new_town[i] == '0':
            count += 1
    return count
```

I agree with @Ajax1234 's answer, but I thought you might like an example that looks closer to your code, with the use of a for loop that demonstrates use of an increment of 2. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I will recommend that you must follow the answer provided by **@Ajax1234** but since you mentioned that you are fairly new(probably not familiar much about `regex`) to python so I would suggest for the current instance you should stick to your code which you are trying to convert to. It is fairly correct just you need to make some amendments to your code(although very small related to indentation). Your amended code would look something like:

```
def count_deaf_rats(town):
    count = 0
    increment = 0
    newTown = town.replace(" ", "")
    while increment <= len(newTown):
        if newTown[increment]=='O':
            count +=1
        increment +=2
return count

#print count_deaf_rats("~O~O~O~OP~O~OO~")
```

This yields the same result as your corresponding java code. Also since `while` loops are not considered much [**handy**](https://www.quora.com/In-what-case-does-the-while-loop-is-more-efficient-than-for-loop-in-Python)(but at some instances much useful also) in python therefore I will insist to use `for` loop as:

```
#Same as above
for increment in range(0,len(newTown),2):
    if newTown[increment] == 'O':
        count +=1
return count
```

Read more about range function [**here**](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)